# Imager resized image not shown (404)

Tags: image-transforms, plugin-imager

I'm just trying out the [imager plugin](https://github.com/aelvan/Imager-Craft#usage). It looks promising!
I've set up the first usage example but I don't see any image on my site in the browser. The image is uploaded properly to the asset source but it seems that Imager is placing its transforms in a subfolder (in this case: '7' ->  http://craft-imager.dev/imager/images/7/nature-13_d4e4e04a52bfbdbeab5ba4d2cf1d1390.jpg)

The subfolder '7' doesn't exists on my machine..

I did some digging around, but I can't figure out what's wrong. The directory 'imager/images' exists and is writable by PHP.

Any idea?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, Imager outputs the url above in the template, but the file doesn't exist on the server? Have you customized your `imagerSystemPath` config setting? What platform are you on?

Comment: Hi André, Yes, that's what Imager outputs. The file doesn't exists on the server. I didn't customize the imagerSystemPath. It's set to: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/imager/'`. I created the `imager` directory, but that didn't help. I also created the `images` directory inside the `imager` directory, but that didn't help either. Any idea? The following code (good old Craft code) shows the image ok by the way; `{% set image = craft.assets().limit(1).first() %} <img src="{{ image.getUrl({ width: 1000 }) }}">` Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm on a Mac. OS X El Capitan running Apache and PHP7 locally.

Comment: I took another look at the imagerSystemPath ;) Thanks! That worked!

Comment: Ok, had you actually overridden it with an incorrect path?

Comment: I had left it untouched. So the default value was active I guess.

Comment: Would you mind adding what worked for you as an official answer @WiegerJelsma in case someone else runs into this?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

I have this line inside my config.
`define('BASEPATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../') . '/');`

And inside the imager config file `imager.php` I have: 
`'.dev' => array('imagerSystemPath' => str_replace('craft/','images/', BASEPATH),`

So, make sure the paths are all set according to your environment / directory structure.